# How to create a multiline regex in java- out of bounds exception

Tags: java, regex, unicode, rtf

I am trying to match any line between the \b in the following (extracted using HTMLParser from Tika). There are several such sections in the whole document:

```
\par }{\b\f1\fs24\ul\insrsid14762702 Data}{\insrsid14762702 
\par Catheter Depth:\tab N/A
\par 
\par }{\b\f1\fs24\ul\insrsid14762702 Analysis Settings}{\insrsid14762702 
\par Upright:\tab 11:06:12
\par Duration:\tab 08:53:13
\par Total:\tab 19:59:25
\par }{\b\f1\fs24\ul\insrsid14762702 Another section}{\insrsid14762702 
\par Stuff
\par }{\b\f1\fs24\ul\insrsid14762702 And again}{\insrsid14762702
```

My code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\b\\f1\\fs24\\ul\\insrsid14762702.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
ArrayList<String> arr= new ArrayList<String>();
while (matcher.find()) {
       arr.add(matcher.group());
     }
 for(String name : arr){
 System.out.println("HIHIHI"+ name);
 }
```

This gives me a

```
Illegal Unicode escape sequence near index 13
(\b\f1\fs24\ul\insrsid14762702.*)
             ^
```

This also happens for the backslash pre `insrsid14762702`

Fair enough, so I then quad escaped the troublesome bits

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\b\\f1\\fs24\\\\ul\\\\insrsid14762702.*)");
```

....which gives me no matches.

I suspect I'm in some kind of unicode? meets regex situation but can't seem to get the answer to the matching.- I know I won't be matching the lines between the patterns just yet but need to straighten out the initial match first.

Comment: Use `"(\\\\b\\\\f1\\\\fs24\\\\ul\\\\insrsid14762702.*)"`.

Comment: That worked. Can you put as an answer- any chance you could add how to make it match everything to the next (\\\\b\\\\f1\\\\fs24\\\\ul\\\\insrsid14762702.*) ie multiline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`Pattern.quote()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(" + Pattern.quote("\\b\\f1\\fs24\\ul\\insrsid14762702") + ".*)")
```

Comment: OK. Although I'm not getting the lines between the pattern

Comment: @SebastianZeki sounds like you're looking for the [`Pattern.DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) option.